# Does single page application pattern applicable for medium size application?

Tags: design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-2, single-page-application

I have come across the SPA design pattern and have a doubt whether this is applicable for a small complete application such as Employee Attendance system or similar application. This will have minimum 5 views and several controllers or actions to be implemented. How does the SPA pattern solve this? Please clarify my doubt as I am very new to this pattern.

Comment: Actually doing some research into this as well, (watching this set of videos at the moment, I can highly recommend it. http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/spa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPA is a possibility, although its goal is really to improve throughput by not using Server Redirects very often through very high turnover websites. You substitute your postbacks for AJAX/JSON calls.

From what you are describing, the standard MVC pattern would be fine for what you are looking to do. You can still convert your actions to use JSON at a later time.

Answer (score 1):

Sigeleton pattern will control number of instance, it will be only one. It is helpful in any case if a single instance is sufficient for your work. For eg. you can never Create a Employee instance as sigeleton, they are generally those classes which do plain processing.

So no matter what is the scale of your bussiness application , you can use it, if single instance id sufficient for your application. Common eg is controller, but again any MVC frame work will be sufficient to achieve this.